# wpf показать/скрыть окно из трэя

Tags: wpf

нужно по нажатию на иконку в трее показать/скрыть окно.
в данный момент: если окно было свернуто при скрытии то показывается тоже свернутым, аналогично при развернутом. как сделать чтобы при показе свернутого окна оно показывалось на экране и выходило на передний план?
"Развернуто" означает обычный вид, не на весь экран

```
notifyicon.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(showhideform);

private void showhideform(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            Hide();
            ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Show();
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowState указывает сотсояние окна(можно и развернуть окно). Topmost на время делает окно с признаком "поверх всех", что бы гарантированно вывести его наверх, а потом параметр можно снять. Activate() признаться не понмю, но чему то помогал :-)

```
 Show();
 Topmost = true;
 WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
 Activate();
 Topmost = false;
```